# Eclipse cannot read io for vertx

Tags: java, eclipse, vert.x

Today I want to start something new with java, vert.x I have basic informations from their website but when I want to apply what I learned I found myself behind an exception of import cannot be resolved for import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle,
I mention that I already have a vertx core jar on referenced libraries and I checked if the class exists.
So any idea ?!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use Maven or Gradle instead of the built-in Eclipse build system. There is a good example [here](http://vertx.io/blog/my-first-vert-x-3-application/).

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanx for help but I restart my eclipse and everything goes well.